# How do I use Codeception unit tests with Slim Framework 3?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim, codeception

I have run into a few problems trying to make Codeception work with my Slim Framework project.

First, I cannot call a service/repository/model from a unit class without it being in the same namespace. When the tests are run, the following code block results in:

> [Error] Class 'OMIS\Services\UserService' not found`

```
// tests
public function testUser()
{
   $userService = new UserService();

   $this->tester->assertNotNull($userService->find(1));
}
```

Secondly, I am trying to get Codeception to interact with a testing database I have set up. Because I am using Laravel's Eloquent ORM I thought that enabling the Laravel ORM module for Codeception in `unit.suite.yml` might work as there is no Slim module available for unit testing, but I get the following error when running the tests:

> ExampleTest: UserPHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client' not found in /Users/me/dev/project/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Laravel5.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client' not found in /Users/Me/dev/project/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Laravel5.php on line 13

Here is the relevant part of my `bootstrap/app.php` file

```
session_start();
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Load environment variables
$dotenv = new Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../');
$dotenv->load();

$container = require __DIR__.'/../config/container.php';

$app = $container->get(App::class);

$config = new Config(__DIR__.'/../config/database.php');
$db = $config->get('db');

$capsule = new Capsule();
$capsule->addConnection($db);

$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();

require __DIR__.'/../config/dependencies.php';
require __DIR__.'/../config/services.php';
require __DIR__.'/../config/controllers.php';

require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';

// Middleware
```